# How to pass environment variables from a Next.js app to packages in a turborepo repository?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, turborepo

I have a Next.js app (test1) that uses a turborepo repository with multiple packages. I want to pass environment variables defined in the Next.js app to the packages in the turborepo repository.

I found one solutions to achieve this:

Using the cross-env package to set environment variables in the test1 app's package.json file and then access them in the packages' package.json files using a prebuild script.

but I'm not sure if this is best approach. Are there any best practices or considerations that I should keep in mind when passing environment variables from a Next.js app to packages in a turborepo repository?